# Measure to sum combined value and display for each individual row

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below I have a table

Table1

```
User       Month    Value
Cosmo      1         25
Kramer     1         25
Vandelay   1         25
Cosmo      2         25
Kramer     2         25
Vandelay   2         25
```

In a matrix I'd like to be able to display the following

```
User      Month 1      Month 2
Cosmo       75           75
Kramer      75           75
Vandelay    75           75
```

I'd like for this measure to show the sum of the selected individuals for each individual.

So far I've tried with ALLEXCEPT. But this seems to Ignore all filters and sum everything, regardless of other columns such as a date.

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Value]); ALLEXCEPT(Table1[User]))
```

I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote another TV show from the last millennium: "Missed it, by that much!"

I'm reading your requirement as needing to include the data from all selected users, but respect any other filters?  If so I would use something like this:

```
=CALCULATE( SUM ( Table1[Value] ) , ALLSELECTED ( Table1[User] ) )
```